# Multiple Vary HTTP headers or one combined?

Tags: http, http-headers, vary

**Question:** What is the best way to send `Vary` HTTP header when server accept gzip/deflate connections AND serve a different content for mobile clients?

I see two possible variants but I cannot find any useful information whether they are correct and/or supported by most proxies and search engines:

1. Combine variants to a single line: `Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent`
2. Send two separate headers:

`Vary: Accept-Encoding`

`Vary: User-Agent`

Any information or link to appropriate W3C standard are welcome :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both are valid (and mean the same thing).

And no, the W3C isn't relevant here. You will need to look into the IETF RFCs 7230 and 7231.

Comment: It bears mentioning those variants are - despite being gramatically different - semantically *identical*

Comment: Thanks, Julian! I should mention that according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.2 (RFC 7230 Section 3.2.2) you've provided in your answer it is _recommended_ to combine headers into one string but _allowed_ to separate. Not sure if it's applicable to Vary header though.

Comment: "unless either the entire field value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list" -  quoting selectively isn't helpful....

Answer (score 0):

Multiple header fields with the same name are allowed for two cases:

1. `Set-Cookie`
2. All header fields where value is always a list (values seperated by commas)

Examples: `Accept-Encoding`, `Vary`, ...

RFC 7230 - 3.2.2

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same
>   field    name in a message unless either the entire field value for
>   that    header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]
>   or the header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).
>
> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field 
>   name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the
>   semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to 
>   the combined field value in order, separated by a comma.  The order
>   in which header fields with the same field name are received is
>   therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field
>   value; a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when
>   forwarding a message.
>
> Note: In practice, the "Set-Cookie" header field ([RFC6265]) often
>     appears multiple times in a response message and does not use the
>     list syntax, violating the above requirements on multiple header
>     fields with the same name.  Since it cannot be combined into a
>     single field-value, recipients ought to handle "Set-Cookie" as a
>     special case while processing header fields.  (See Appendix A.2.3
>     of [Kri2001] for details.)